# PHP non-client coder class execution

Tags: php, oop, class-design

**Simply question of theory**

When building a class that is not going to be used by any other client-coders, what is the best method of execution? Consider the following:

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo();
        $this->bar();
    }

    public function foo(){ //do something }

    public function bar(){ //do something }
}

$test = new Test;
```

As I know exactly what I want this class to do, and the order it should be done in, I simply call the functions during construction. However The same can be done by doing:

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct(){}

    public function foo(){ //do something }

    public function bar(){ //do something }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->foo();
$test->bar();
```

What are the advantages to doing it one way or the other? Be it performance, debugging, etc.

**Edit**

This is a general purpose question. Looking to hear all possibilities and concerns regarding these two ways of executing methods within a class.

Comment: My only concern would be, with calling those methods in the constructor, that a sub-class could potentially override the constructor and those methods would not be called (unless the developer knew to add them in).

Comment: Very valid point. +1 to you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 1st way you can make those functions `private` and use them only within the object itself.

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo();
        $this->bar();
    }

    private function foo(){ //do something }

    private function bar(){ //do something }
}

$test = new Test; 
//so:
$test->foo(); //will throw an error
```

If you make the functions `protected` instead of `private`, any class that inherits from this class would be able to to use the functions (while still not allowing for the functions to be called on the outside)

---

With your second option, any object can call those functions outside the class definition, and depending on your code, you might not want that.

Comment: Valid point. However if there is no client-code happening, should this concern me as the sole programmer?

Comment: @Headspin -- what do u mean by `concern`?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Neal's answer: If you can, make the functions private. That way, if you want to change them later, you know they are only used within their class.

So, to answer you question: The first answer is preferred because is makes your code easier to maintain. Performance wise, there is no difference.